# Any idea how to stop this loop?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

```js
function draw(x, y)
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,110,150,1)";
    ctx.fillRect (x, 370, 20, 20);
    ctx.restore();
    x += 41;
    var loop = setTimeout('draw('+x+','+y+')',70);
}

draw(10, 20);
```

```css
.d{
    width: 93%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" class="d" width="1838" height="1050"></canvas>
```

Comment: It's much preferable to say `setTimeout(function() { draw(x, y); }`.

Comment: When and how do you want to stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loop` needs to be scoped outside of the function. Then calling `clearTimeout` on it will stop the loop.

```
var loop;
function draw(x,y) {
    ...
    loop = setTimeout (...); // no "var"
    ...
}
...
draw (0,0);
setTimeout (function () {
    clearTimeout (loop);
}, 5000); // will stop the loop after 5 seconds
```

Comment: thanks a lot. :) it works. thank you for helping me on my project.

Comment: np. Good luck with your project

Comment: This answer is wrong for several reasons: 1) It doesn't solve the OP's problem. 2) you seem to be confusing `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` 3) it unnecessarily creates a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Right now `draw()` is *always* calling the function `draw()`. To stop that add an `if` before calling `draw()`:

```js
function draw(x, y)
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,110,150,1)";
    ctx.fillRect (x, 370, 20, 20);
    ctx.restore();
    x += 41;

    // Only add another dot if there are fewer than 20 dots
    if (x < 800)
        setTimeout(function() { draw(x, y) }, 70);
}

draw(10, 20);
```

```css
.d {
    width: 93%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" class="d" width="1838" height="1050"></canvas>
```

---

Perhaps a slightly clearer, but more advanced, solution might be to use `setInterval()`, which runs a function every *n* seconds (instead of `setTimeout()` which runs it only *once* after *n* seconds:

```js
function draw(x, y) {    
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


    var loop = setInterval(function() {
        // setInterval() returns an indentifier for the timer; we can cancel 
        // the interval with clearInterval()
        if (x > 800)
            clearInterval(loop)
        ctx.save();
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,110,150,1)";
        ctx.fillRect(x, 370, 20, 20);
        ctx.restore();
        x += 41;
    }, 70)
}

draw(10, 20);
```

```css
.d {
    width: 93%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" class="d" width="1838" height="1050"></canvas>
```

As you can see, this is slightly more efficient, since we don't need to get the `canvas` and `ctx` every time.